# Generating a list through a loop on dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to make a list of colors in dart for my app but, since I don't want this list to be enormous, I'd like to know if there's a way to generate a list given a particular condition. The list is this one:

```
List dateColors = [
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white,
    Colors.white
  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **fill** a `List` with the same value, use `filled`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  final dateColors = List.filled(31, Colors.white);
  print(dateColors);
  // [Color(0xffffffff), ..., Color(0xffffffff)], a total of 31 Colors.white.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's funny that you mentioned the key word here: `generate`. That's the constructor of the `List` type you are looking for.

```dart
List<int>.generate(3, (int index) => index * index); // [0, 1, 4]
```

Check [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) for more info on this constructor.

In your case, you could discard the index that the `generate` constructor is giving you, to build a list that is made of the same objects repeating over and over again. Consider this snippet as an example that may suit your needs

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  final colors = List<Color>.generate(20, (_) => Colors.white); 
  print(colors);
  // Prints [Color(0xffffffff), ..., Color(0xffffffff)], a total of twenty Colors.white.
}
```

you can see that it prints a list of 20 `Color`s, and all of them are white.

Comment: So how would that be in my case?
```List<Color>.generate(31, (Color i) =>  i=Colors.white);```?

Comment: You are on the right path, but the line you suggested won't work because `generate` will provide you with an index of type `int`, and not with a color. I should have built an example that was more related to your question. Consider the example I've added to my edited answer, hope it suits your needs.